# javascript, $.ajax, variable name

Tags: javascript, ajax, scope

I'm trying to iterate over an array and assign a variable with a for loop. So something like this:

```
function Person(name, status){
  this.name = name;
  this.status = status;
}

var status = [];
var array = ["bill","bob","carl","ton"];
function exAjax(function(){
 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   var name = array[i];
   console.log(name); =====> this gives the correct name

   $.ajax({
     url: xxxxxxx,
     success: function(data){
       if(data.stream === null){
         var person = new Person(name, "dead");
         console.log(name); =====> return undefined until the last
         person

         status.push(person);       
       }
     }

   })
   name = "";
 }
})
```

The problem I'm having is that name is not getting into the success function. I thought js keeps traveling upwards to look for the variable if it doesn't exist in it's current scope? I'm getting undefined for the name variable if I try to console.log name! Scope masters what am I doing wrong?

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. By the time the `success` function runs, the `for` loop has already finished. What do you think does the value `i` have after the loop is finished?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Thank you! If I set async: "false" ; for that ajax call will that fix the problem?

Comment: That’s a really horrible way of solving it. Instead, wrap your AJAX call in a closure like this: `(function(i){`…`})(i);`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again. I will try that.

Comment: when you wrap the ajax call how come you you have an (i) at the end of the wrap?

Comment: Just read the link I provided. It’s an IIFE. It creates a function-scoped copy of the variable `i` via a function argument.

Comment: Ok. I will do that. Thank you very much. It's not running properly so I have to do some reading on closures.

Comment: You probably also need to define `name` inside that function as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.queue()`, `$.map()` to maintain scope of `name`. Also, change `status` array to an object having property `status` where value is an array to prevent possible conflict with `this.status` of `Person` object.

Note, you can also chain `.promise(/* queueName */)` to perform tasks at `.then()` when all queued functions in `queueName`, i.e.g., `"status"` have been called, `queueName` `.length` is `0`.

```js
function Person(name, status){
  this.name = name;
  this.status = status;
}

var blob = new Blob(['{"stream":null}'], {type:"application/json"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// change `status` array reference, e.g., to `arr`
var arr = {status:[]};
var array = ["bill","bob","carl","ton"];

$(arr).queue("status", $.map(array, function(curr) {
  return function(next) {
    var name = curr;
    // do asynchronous stuff
    $.ajax({url:url, dataType:"json"})
    .then(function(data) {
       if(data.stream == null){
         var person = new Person(name, "dead");
         console.log(name, person);
         arr.status.push(person);
       }
    })
    .then(next) // call next function in `"status"` queue
  }
}))
.dequeue("status")
.promise("status")
// do stuff when all functions in `"status"` queue have completed,
// `"status"` queue `.length` is `0`
.then(function() {
   // `this` : `arr` as jQuery object
   // `this[0].status`: array containing objects pushed to `arr.status`
   console.log(this[0].status); // $(this).prop("status");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nnayjckc/2/

---

You can alternatively use `$.when()`, `.apply()`, `$.map()`, to return same result

```js
function Person(name, status) {
  this.name = name;
  this.status = status;
}

var blob = new Blob(['{"stream":null}'], {
  type: "application/json"
});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// change `status` array reference, e.g., to `arr`
var arr = {
  status: []
};
var array = ["bill", "bob", "carl", "ton"];

$.when.apply($, $.map(array, function(curr) {
  var name = curr;
  return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: "json"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      if (data.stream == null) {
        var person = new Person(name, "dead");
        console.log(name, person);
        arr.status.push(person);
      }
    })
}))
.then(function() {
  console.log(arr.status)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nnayjckc/3/

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$.ajax` perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request. It means that your `for` loop won't wait for `success` to complete. Instead it will continue with its iteration.

One way (of the many possible solutions), is to make this `$.ajax` `synchronous` with the `async: false` option

**From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

> *async (default: true)*
>   *Type: Boolean*
>   By default, all requests are
>   sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   var name = array[i];
   console.log(name); =====> this gives the correct name

   $.ajax({
     url: xxxxxxx,
     async: false,
     success: function(data){
       if(data.stream === null){
         var person = new Person(name, "dead");
         console.log(name); =====> return undefined until the last
         person

         status.push(person);       
       }
     }

   })
   name = "";
 }
})
```