# Is there an equivalent of a Func<T> or better yet, an ActionBlock in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am trying to make potentially dozens of ajax calls and want to stack them out 4 or 5 concurrently but not fire them all at once. In C# I would use an ActionBlock, and send in my delegate until I'm ready and then start executing.

so, I am attempting to build the same in JavaScript, and have been able to get everything working using $.when and arrays, but I am not able to pass in a delegate to a function with particular parameters.

I have tried fn.apply and fn.bind, but both of them execute immediately while trying to create the execution chain.

In c#, the signature would simply be :

```
public Push(Action|Func<T> methodToCall){...}
```

Then I would invoke it recursively in the .then handler of the $.when

Comment: you talk a bit about what you've tried - but haven't shown any of it - perhaps it's a simple mistake you've made, perhaps it isn't - how can we tell? in general, it looks like you may be on the right track

Comment: Have you looked at using promises?

Comment: @ACOMIT001 - he mentions `$.when` - so, that would be a yes I'd say

Comment: Just like C#, Typescript supports function<t>, in addition it supports async/await in the same manner.  It's only a slight twist to get it because it's so similar to C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At jQuery you can use `.queue(queueName)` to set an array of N synchronous functions or asynchronous procedures which can be called in sequence, that is when the previous function returns a `Promise` or other value; `.promise(queueName)` to wait for all functions in `queueName` array to be called; `.then()` chained to `.promise(queueName)` to perform action when `queueName` jQuery promise object is fulfilled.

The same pattern can also be composed without using jQuery; by using `Array.prototype.shift()`, `Promise` constructor or other `Promise` object, and recursion or repeated scheduling.

See

- [Execute function queue in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028368/execute-function-queue-in-javascript/)
- [javascript, $.ajax, variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758499/javascript-ajax-variable-name/38758696#38758696)
- [multiple, sequential fetch() Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034574/multiple-sequential-fetch-promise/38034756?s=4|1.8973#38034756)

Comment: Thanks, the shift() pointed me to the right direction. Queueing the function pointer and  params then recursively calling it until the array is empty will work.