# How to define total length of a function(data)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing the following:

```
  $.getJSON(url,function(data){
    var totalQueries = data.length;
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
```

But this one looks like to be wrong:

```
var totalQueries = data.length;
```

As by the end of it I check for the last item and it never happens:

```
  if (i === totalQueries - 1) {
    myId = item.pageid;
    console.log(myId);
    newQuery();
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting console errors?  Have you tried debugging?  How confident are you that `data` is an array and not an object?

Comment: I am sure `data` is an array as I can read it, I get no errors as the code is correct, but I can see that `console.log(myId);` doesn't happen which means the conditional isn't happening @AlexanderNied

Comment: `total length of a function(data)` makes no sense ... you're getting the length property of the returned parsed JSON. If the top level "object" is an Array, the length property is the number of elements in the array

Comment: perhaps an example of `data` would help - perhaps the last item in the array is not an object with a pageid property

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly, I knew it wasn't making any sense, that's why I have ended up on here. Is there anyway I could do to know the end of it?

Comment: @JaromandaX here it is jsFiddle, check the beginning of function `wikiText() {` where I get the data and the end of that when I run the conditional

Comment: @rob.m - I think you accidentally omitted the JSFiddle link from your above comment...

Comment: @AlexanderNied ouch https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/411/

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry, this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/411/

Comment: `i` is a string `"parse"` and `totalQueries` is `undefined` at linked jsfiddle `console.log(i, typeof i, totalQueries)`. What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to perform tasks asynchronously, or in a sequence, then do stuff when all of the tasks have completed?

Comment: @guest271314 I am trying to find the last id of the queries and then start again to query starting from that id, the way i start again is by calling `newQuery();` and passing the latest `id myId = item.pageid;` at the end of the loop to `newQuery();` api parameter `eicontinue=2|"+myId+"` so that i can start again the calls starting from the last id, does it make sense?

Comment: You can `return jQuery.getJSON()` jQuery promise from the functions which makes the asynchronous calls. Use `$.when()` and `Function.prototype.apply()` to perform a task when all elements of array return a jQuery promise object. Or you can use jQuery `.queue()` and `.promise()` to achieve similar result.

Comment: @guest271314 could you elaborate it more into something i could test pls?

Comment: @guest271314 I just added `.promise().done(function( arg1 ) {
      myId = item.pageid;
      console.log(myId);
      newQuery();
  });` at the end of the function but the console says `item` is not defined

Comment: doing `.queue().promise(function..` gives me `$.getJSON(...).queue is not a function`

Comment: @rob.m Using `$.when()` https://jsfiddle.net/s5f4dc6e/. Note, `.queue()` requires a `queueName` parameter equal to `queueName` passed to `.promise()`. `.queue()` cannot not be chained to `$.getJSON()`, you would use `.queue()` to call N functions in sequence, then `.promise()` chained before `.then()` to schedule further tasks, which could include calling same function which returns `.queue()` with `.promise()` chained again

Comment: @guest271314 oh ok, anyhow you could apply that to the linekd fiddle so that i can better understand it? I am not too familiar with queue and i am not sure where to insert it then

Comment: See [Execute function queue in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32028368/), [javascript, $.ajax, variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38758499/)

Comment: @guest271314 I think I have a much simpler solution, since the calls of `newQuery()` are the same as per `wikitext()`, I made 2 `counters`, one for `newQuery()` and one for `wikitext()`, and I check when they get o each last one, and when they finally match in the number, i start a `newQuery()` https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/458/

Answer (score 0):

`data` is object use `Object.keys(data).length;` to count and here you object look like,

`i` is `parse`

```
{
  "parse": {
    "title": "Colegio Nueva Granada",
    "pageid": 2340380,
    "text": {
      "*": "<div class=...."
    },
    "langlinks": []
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried assigning `var totalQueries = Object.keys(data).length;` but I never get the `console.log(myId);`

Comment: because `i` is object key `parse` not interger, you need to create counter.

Comment: can you edit my fiddle so that i better understand your answer please? Because I am not sure to put the counter

Comment: here https://jsfiddle.net/ewwink/72uL633e/ edited: #65, $199, added: #66, #197, #198, 204# beware it load huge file, disable your internet before it hang your browser

Comment: hey thanks, I am not sure why it is loading so many if the continue parameter is 2 and i can see a lot of duplicate ids tho

Comment: I think I have a much simpler solution, since the calls of `newQuery()` are the same as per `wikitext()`, I made 2 `counters`, one for `newQuery()` and one for `wikitext()`, and I check when they get o each last one, and when they finally match in the number, i start a `newQuery()` https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/458/