# two dimensional arrays not pushing correct index values when looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have 2 api calls, and they both push values into a multidimensional array, in order to associate the corresponding value results from the api calls.

When I run the following:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(spacetime), null, "\t");
```

The console gives me:

```
[
  {
    "Title":
      [
        "Battle of Baekgang","Victory Tests","Everett massacre"
      ],
    "Space": [
      "United States"
    ],
    "Time": [
      "27 - 28 August 663 CE ",
      "27 - 28 August 663 CE 19 May 1945 – 22 August 1945 ",
      "27 - 28 August 663 CE 19 May 1945 – 22 August 1945 November 5, 1916 "
    ]
  }
]
```

But the values don't match, I have 3 objects with `Title`, one with `Space` and 3 with `Time`

This is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/589/), it is a bit long so a bit of quick guide:

1. On line `69` we run the first set of calls with `wikiText()`, `500`, they need to be this much otherwise we wouldn't find results matching the criteria. And we push the current `title` and the current `date` like this:

   ```
     spacetime[0].Title.push(curTitle);
     spacetime[0].Time.push(d);
   ```
2. On this call we do a lot of checks, but we want to concentrate on the lines `108` - `128` - `149` and `169`, basically these are the lines that run the second `api call`: `countryPage();`

On the second api call, we check if the current page has any other matching criteria, and if so we `push` the result into the multi dimensional array called `Space[]`.

This last `push` tho, it is related to the call we did when doing one of the `else` on `wikiText()` meaning we didn't find `space` so we launch `countryPage();` to find it.

But the relations don't happen, they get `pushed` but not in the correct order nor the correct number of items as per the first part above of this question. It is driving me nuts for 2 days tbh.

Comment: Try to log the info before you push it to the arrays. Maybe the info is not arriving correctly and therefore you are not seeing it in the result

Comment: @alexhenkel I have tried soo many different ways, this is the last try when there is missing info but before there was a mismatch with space and time and the title. Really can't get my head around it:(

Comment: @RobertoMarras The code at linked jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/589/ at 
present Question appears to be the substantially the same code at linked jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/411/   at this Question [How to define total length of a function(data)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45395938/). Why do you not include all relevant details of your inquiry at a single Question?

Comment: @guest271314 because I am trying to do it and work it out myself bit by bit and ask the single questions when I need to, also because this way I will learn. For example now I am stack here, can you help? https://pastebin.com/yeMwjvsr

Comment: Using `$.when()` , `.apply()` or `.queue()` and `.promise()` should return expected result, as suggested at other Question

Comment: @guest271314 check the chat